Determine who applied a CU patch
Have a possible user that is implementing the CU incorrectly (under the wrong login)
I am Looking for a way to determine what account was used to install a CU update.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is probably located in the numerous log files. There is a SQL Server summary file, log file, and a Windows MSI log file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver16

You need to have the logon audit enable to be able to do a search to who logged into the server in the eventlog.

If it's enabled, check event log 4624, and check if it correlate to the timing when the CU update occured, but it's not hard proof, but a good indication.
